# Why the netCDF4 file size are so different from the write ways?

Tags: python, netcdf, filesize

I have several text files store 2 dimension data(same shape) with different times and different groups. Now I want to convert these data to ONE netCDF file with several netCDF Groups. Each group's variable has the same dimensions like :`dimensions:{time=62, lat=118, lon=104}`. And I write the data in three ways. Codes are written in python3.7 and netCDF4 package.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset, date2num, date2index
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def initialize(fpath):
    rootgrp = Dataset(fpath, 'w')
    rootgrp.createDimension('time', 62)
    rootgrp.createDimension('lat', 118)
    rootgrp.createDimension('lon', 104)

    times = rootgrp.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time', ))
    lats = rootgrp.createVariable('lat', 'f4', ('lat', ))
    lons = rootgrp.createVariable('lon', 'f4', ('lon', ))

    lats.units = 'degrees north'
    lons.units = 'degrees east'
    times.units = 'hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0'
    times.calendar = 'gregorian'
    datetimes = [
        datetime(2020, 3, 1, 8) + n * timedelta(hours=12) for n in range(62)
    ]

    lats[:] = np.linspace(-40, 40, 118)
    lons[:] = np.linspace(80, 160, 104)
    times[:] = date2num(datetimes, times.units, times.calendar)
    return rootgrp


def write(fpath, data, **kwargs):
    if not os.path.exists(fpath):
        rootgrp = initialize(fpath)
    else:
        rootgrp = Dataset(fpath, 'r+')

    grppath = kwargs['grppath']
    varname = kwargs['varname']
    grp = rootgrp.createGroup(grppath)
    if varname in grp.variables:
        var = grp.variables[varname]
    else:
        var = grp.createVariable(varname,
                                 'f4', ('time', 'lat', 'lon'),
                                 zlib=True,
                                 least_significant_digit=1)

    times = rootgrp.variables['time']
    datetimes = kwargs.get('datetimes', None)
    if datetimes is None:
        time_index = slice(None)
    else:
        time_index = date2index(datetimes, times, calendar=times.calendar)

    print(var[time_index, :, :].shape)
    print(data.shape)
    var[time_index, :, :] = data
    rootgrp.close()


def get_data(groups, datetimes):
    shape = (118, 104)
    size = shape[0] * shape[1]
    all_group = {}
    for group in groups:
        data_list = []
        for time in datetimes:
            data = np.random.random(size).reshape(shape)
            data_list.append(data)
        all_group[group] = data_list
    return all_group


def way1(dateimes, grouped_data):
    for i, time in enumerate(datetimes):
        for group, data in grouped_data.items():
            write('way1.nc',
                  data[i],
                  grppath=group,
                  varname='random',
                  datetimes=time)


def way2(datetimes, grouped_data):
    for group in grouped_data:
        all_data = np.stack(grouped_data[group])
        write('way2.nc',
              all_data,
              grppath=group,
              varname='random',
              datetimes=datetimes)


def way3(datetimes, grouped_data):
    for group, data in grouped_data.items():
        for i, time in enumerate(datetimes):
            write('way3.nc',
                  data[i],
                  grppath=group,
                  varname='random',
                  datetimes=time)


groups = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
datetimes = [
    datetime(2020, 3, 1, 8) + n * timedelta(hours=12) for n in range(62)
]
grouped_data = get_data(groups, datetimes)
way1(datetimes, grouped_data)
way2(datetimes, grouped_data)
way3(datetimes, grouped_data)
```

The files written by the three ways are all the same(Variable's ChunkSizes = (62U, 118U, 104U)) except the file size.

way 1: 495,324,392 Bytes（disk's 503.3 MB)

way 2: 15,608,108 Bytes（disk's 16.7 MB)

way 3: 15,608,108 Bytes（disk's 16.7 MB)

I'm wondering if anyone could explain for me.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the actual array and chunk sizes are the same? You can use the `h5ls` command line tool (included in the HDF-5 installation) to get more information about the storage and chucks (because a NetCDF-4 file is also HDF-5 file). Perhaps this information can also be found with the HDF-Viewer. But I would use `h5ls -r -v yourfile.nc` on both your files and then use a diff viewer to compare and look for differences.

Comment: Hi, @titusjan. Thanks for your help. I have followed your instructions and print out the `h5ls` command's result. There are lots of diffenences between them,but i don't realise what does it mean. The two NC files created by my code are ALL THE SAME means the data exported to the NC files are all what i want, except the file size are not the same. I want understand why could those different so much.

Comment: For every dataset there is a `Chunks` line that shows the actual chunk sizes. Are these as expected? The same question for the `Storage` line. If not, you must do some debugging. Take one dataset as an example and look in detail how it is created. If you want further help from us you must make a test program with artificial data so that we can reproduce the issue. Make an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The snippets that you gave are not complete. That is, I cannot run them and reproduce your problem.

Comment: @titusjan It is very kind of you to give me these suggestions. I have edited the question, gave a complete  code snippets  use some hard coding, and add a third way of writing data. I think the code snippets now can run in computers which the required packages were installed.  I am still confused why the file size different in way1 and way2, but the file size are the same in way2 and way3.

Comment: My compliments and an upvote for creating a proper MRE. See my answer on what I've found out so far.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but I have to go sleep now and want to share what I found out so far. The `h5ls` output showed indeed that all datasets are the same size and chunks, so that's not the issue.

In your program you test if a netCDF file or variable exists, and then only create it if it doesn't exist yet. However, you don't test for groups, you always create them. By changing `grp = rootgrp.createGroup(grppath)` into the following lines, the size of `way1.nc` is reduced to 19 MB.

```
if grppath in rootgrp.groups:
    grp = rootgrp[grppath]
else:
    grp = rootgrp.createGroup(grppath)
```

When you delete an object from an HDF5 file, the file size remains the same (see section 5.5.2. deleting a Dataset from a File and Reclaiming Space of the [HDF5 user guide](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/HDF5-1.8.7/UG/UG_frame10Datasets.html)). So I suspect that creating a group with the same name over and over again will allocate storage space but doesn't free the old group's disk space, thus creating a memory leak. I don't know why this happens only in way 1, and not in way 3.

Also I don't understand yet why `way1.nc` is still slightly larger (19 MB) than the others (15 MB).

Finally, because you only call the `initialize` function if the netCDF file doesn't exist, you must be careful to delete the output of the previous run before you start the program. You can easily forget this so I recommend that you modify your code so that `initialize` is always executed at the program start.

Comment: It's a good suggestion to move the `initialize` function to the program start. But the question is still not figured out. Whether it is necessary to test the existence of a group before create it or not is not the key point, see the [netCDF4_API_documentation](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.Dataset.createGroup). Even if i test the existence of a group before create it, the size of `way1.nc` is still about 490MB in my computer(macOS 10.13.6). Maybe i need to read over the link you provided to find if there is an answer. Still thanks!